# Swaping ETH to DAI on Uniswap

Tags: truffle, remix, truffle-migration, infura, ganache-cli

I don't get why when trying to deploy my contract it says that gas estimation errored.
Forked Mainnet with `ganache-cli -f <INFURA_ID>`
Trying to deploy and execute following code:

```
pragma solidity ^0.7.0;

import 'IERC20.sol';
import 'IUniswap.sol';

contract Uniswap_Swap {
  address internal constant UNISWAP_ROUTER_ADDRESS = 0x7a250d5630B4cF539739dF2C5dAcb4c659F2488D;
  address daiAddress = 0x6B175474E89094C44Da98b954EedeAC495271d0F;
  IUniswap public uniswapRouter;

  constructor() {
    uniswapRouter = IUniswap(UNISWAP_ROUTER_ADDRESS);
  }
  function convertEthToDai(uint daiAmount) public payable {
    uint deadline = block.timestamp + 15;
    uniswapRouter.swapExactETHForTokens{ value: msg.value }(daiAmount, getPathForETHtoDAI(), address(this), deadline);
    (bool success,) = msg.sender.call{ value: address(this).balance }("");
    require(success, "refund failed");
  }
  function getPathForETHtoDAI() private view returns (address[] memory) {
    address[] memory path = new address[](2);
    path[0] = uniswapRouter.WETH();
    path[1] = daiAddress;

    return path;
  }
  receive() payable external {}
}
```

Any help is much appreciated

EDIT: migration file

```
const UniswapExample = artifacts.require("UniswapExample");

module.exports = function (deployer) {
  deployer.deploy(UniswapExample);
};
```

tried it with remix and directly through terminal. Even wrote a python code to call. Closest I got was with python and Excessive_Input_Error. Though I thought no liquidity needed to add due to mainnet fork.

Comment: What does the migration script look like? The contract's constructor is trivial it seems unlikely to be the cause of issues.

Comment: Since we're using all the ETH I don't think the refund part is required. Because no ETH would be left to refund. That could be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think I met the same problem, although forking the mainnet with hardhat. This set it right when using web3py:

```
    preparedTx  = myContract.functions.myFun(*params).buildTransaction({
        'chainId': 31337,
        'gas': 700000, 
        'gasPrice': web3.toWei('1', 'gwei'),
        'nonce': nonce,
    })
```

Note the gasPrice set low and chainId switched to the local RPC, which is documented somewhere in the hardhat/ganache.